# How to make an svg object clickable

Tags: javascript, svg

When can I make the object clickable.

For example:

`<object data="img/test.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />`

When I add onclick it doesn't work.

Important notice: I need to have an object and not img, due to the fact that I'm making some manipulation to the svg once that it is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("svg").addEventListener('click', doSomething);

function doSomething(e) {
  // code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add `click` event programatically?

Like this:

```
<object id="svgId" data="img/test.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />

var el = document.getElementById("svgId").onclick=yourMethod;


yourMethod()
{
   // Your method which would do something when it's clicked?
}
```

Or a `el .addEventListener("click", yourMethod, false);`